# Origin of "A message from our sponsors" ads?

Tags: windows, internet, bittorrent, adware

It looks like BitTorrent, at least on Windows computers, installs some sort of very well-hidden adware which occasionally, when one clicks on a Web link, displays a white screen saying "And now a message from our sponsors" with a Flash ad. This ad behaves in the same way as legitimate 'sponsor ads' -- the close link in the upper left works, for example.

To see this behavior, install BitTorrent, uninstall it immediately, and start browsing a site that doesn't have these sorts of ad interruptions; you'll see them sooner or later.

This appears to happen in all browsers. (I've seen it in Firefox and seen references to it in Chrome.) Googling turns up a lot of people asking about this, but no answer yet. The ad doesn't appear to be coming from a toolbar, a process, or anything in C:\Users\ or C:\Users\All Users.

This was asked once before at https://superuser.com/questions/773532/how-to-hunt-down-the-source-of-redirect-to-advertisements . I hope that this version provides enough precision that it becomes possible to track down the cause; this isn't about hunting down all sources of ad redirects, it's about tracking down a particular (and very elusive) one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you receive a BitTorrent app from an untrusted source. Never install anything from a random web site, always use CNET or the official site, because they are liable to give you malware with your EXE install.

If you are on Windows, take a look at Installed Apps.  Some "ethical" adware is polite enough to leave an entry in Installed Apps, so that you can easily uninstall it.  If it's not one of these, you might be screwed.  You might have to try to revert to a restore point or a backup in order to get rid of the adware.

You can also try installing Ad Block. If you are very lucky, the adware will be using a known ad spam site and Ad Block will stop the ads.

Comment: I must mention that there have been times where a re-packaging download existed at CNET before. In one case hundreds of people had 5stared the download early, and hundreds more after 1starred the same download later for re-packaged install containing malware, insisting that cnet didn't do anything about it. Whenever possible get your downloads direct from the real source.

Comment: I downloaded from bittorrent.com itself -- apparently even the official download is ridiculously adwared. Among other things, it installs a Yahoo toolbar, a program that monitors for the Yahoo toolbar being removed (fortunately this one shows up in Programs and Features and so can be uninstalled), this thing, and who knows what else. It also uninstalled NoScript; reinstalling that seems to have helped. But I'd like to get to the bottom of "A message from our sponsors"...

Comment: For the future -- if I need to get BitTorrent again, where should I get it from in a way that won't riddle my computer with adware, since the official site can't be trusted?